# Showing data from controller in twig file Opencart 3.0.2.0

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

I have added this line to  catalog/controller/product/category.php

```
$data['string1'] = "string 1";
```

before

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
```

and in catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/product/category.twig
 replaced

```
 <h4 class="name"><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }} </a></h4>
```

with this line

```
<h4 class="name"><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }}  {{  string1 }} </a></h4>
```

but it shows nothing, what did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you clear caches? Journal cache, ocmod cache, twig cache?

Comment: I tried to print tt in .twig file directly and it printed it, I don't think it is a cahce problem

Comment: <h4 class="name"><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }} tt {{  string1 }} </a></h4>

I made it like this, and it printed tt,

Comment: Are you sure category.php is not cached?

Comment: mmm, I didn't check that, I will check it,

Comment: I have removed all the files in /storage/cahce, and /public_html/system/storage/cache, but the same no difference,

Comment: In category.php try `echo 'test';` Is it showing?

Comment: no it didn't show

Comment: It is cached...

Comment: what are the other places to delete caches?

Comment: I have did this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUCfk.png, I have turn off caching from developer settings

Comment: I commented the following lines,
   //$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
   //$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
and the changes were shown immediately in the web page

this means it is not cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, I forgot to refresh modification. That was the problem.
Extension -> Modification -> refresh.